# Passing the Context of a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer based app , a `Home Class extends AppCompatActivity` in which i switch between the different tabs of the Navigation Drawer and a HomeFragment that represents the " HOME " tab . 
In the other hand i made a " ReadRSS " class with a constructor taking Context as parameter .
I want to Instantiate the " ReadRSS " class in my HomeFragment , if i use keywrod this i got an error says :

```
ReadRSS (android.content.Context)         in ReadRSS cannot be applied 
to      (com.example.essat.essat.HomeFragment)
```

If i try to pass `getAcitivty()` or `getContext()` i get an error says :

```
unreachable statement
```

here is My Code for more details :

```
public class ReadRSS extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public ReadRSS (Context context){
    this.context=context;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
}
// Other Methods ... 
}
```

HomeFragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ReadRSS readRSS = new ReadRSS(// I Pass them all Here );
    readRSS.execute();

}

}
```

In My Home Class i call the Fragment using the code below :

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Home_Container,new HomeFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and reuse it again in a Switch Statement with the other tabs , so that when the app launches it show the home fragment and if u ever changed the tab you can come back using the "HOME" tab.

I Hope You can help me Solve this error or suggest an other way of doing it .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Well, you should be able to make ReadRSS readRSS = new ReadRSS(getContext()); otherwise pls check and post your imports.

Comment: I passed the getContext() there and it didn't work ,
Just a Writing mistake .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, sure - that's because you have return statement before ReadRSS initialize.

Change order to:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ReadRSS readRSS = new ReadRSS(// I Pass them all Here );
    readRSS.execute();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

And it would be ok.

Comment: Oh Silly Me HAHAHAHAHA ! Thnk You So Much ! it works :D

Comment: i wish i can rate your answer but , i'm still new in the stack

Answer (score 0):

You have the line:

```
ReadRSS readRSS = new ReadRSS();
```

But your ReadRSS class is asking for args in the parameter? Or do you have another empty constructor that you've not included here?

Where is it where you're calling getContext() thats causing the error unreachable statement? Unreachable statement means its impossible for the path of execution to get to that line... i.e. theres a return statement above it, or an exception is thrown above it.

Comment: I pass it as a Constructor in ReadRSS , ( Post Edited )

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved By Goltsev Eugene 
 I just needed to switch the order between the ReadRSS instantiation and the return statement .

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
ReadRSS readRSS = new ReadRSS(// I Pass them all Here );
readRSS.execute();

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Thanks To You All .

Answer (score -1):

You can get context in onAttach()

```
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

to ReadRSS class.

```
ReadRSS readRSS = new ReadRSS(context);
```

Comment: Try to get activity in onAttach()